# how to use the function setState in main file

Tags: flutter

is it possible to use `setState()` function on main.dart  because it has not a statfulWidget . how could i use it or is there another solution or function that have the same functionality

Comment: "or is there another solution or function that have the same functionality" - `ValueListenableBuilder` for example

Comment: can you clarify on your usecase.. why do you need to use it in the first place..

Answer (score 1):

The best way is using a state manager.
My main.dart Works with get, like this :

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.light);


    try {
      return GetX<AppController>(
        builder: (ac) => (
          _buildWithTheme(context, ac)
        )
      );
    } catch(_){}

  }

Widget _buildWithTheme(BuildContext context, AppController state) {

    return  MaterialApp(
      title: 'APP',
      theme:  makeAppTheme(),      
      darkTheme: makeAppTheme(),     
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      initialRoute: '/',
      locale: setLocale(state),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`setState` can be used when changing the value:

```
int i = 0;
```

---

```
setState(() {
  i = 1;
});
```

---

```
print(i);
```

Result:

```
I/flutter ( 2492): 1
```